# Date issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, date

The code below mentioned is for comparision of date. Both **date1** and **mydate** have similar values,But if i compare its not entering **if** loop. Any help appreciated

```
 var date_arr = new Array( "Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
var Avl_date =  document.getElementById("Available_Date").value;
var V_date1 = Avl_date.split('-');
var date1 = new Date (V_date1[2], date_arr.indexOf(V_date1[1]),V_date1[0]);

var myDate = new Date(); 
myDate.setHours(0,0,0);

 //Thu Dec 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) --> date1
 //Thu Dec 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) --> mydate

 if(myDate.getTime() === date1.getTime())
{
  //Not entering the loop
}
```

Comment: Have you used `console.log` to show the results for both `.getTime()` functions?

Comment: What is an _if loop_? `if` is for comparing things, not looping.

Comment: functionalities are not added in the code.If its true then,some thing should be displayed

Comment: You set the hours, minutes, and seconds, but not milliseconds.

Comment: You might want to put a `console.log(myDate.getTime(), date1.getTime())` to see exactly what is being compared.  It might not be what you expect.

Comment: You might find it simpler to use `+myDate == +date1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the milliseconds of `myDate` to `0`, so it keeps its original milliseconds. Use:

```
myDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar is correct. setting the milliseconds will solve your problem.